# Corona update and my code got error and i didn't modify anything

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-director

Ok so i have a huge problem, i make a game and i worked in past for this project and for a while i didn't modify anything in code , and today when i tried to open it in Corona Simulator  it gives me this  error , it said something about the menu.lua and director class, is possible that the problem to be the director class? i mean i have to take an update of that or something like that , i will attach a image of the error i get.

Here is my code from Menu

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local director = require("director")
local sprite = require("sprite")

new = function( params )

local menuDisplay = display.newGroup()

local background = display.newImage("bgmenu.jpg")
background.x = 240
background.y = 160
local spriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("sprite1.png", 54,70)
local monsterSet = sprite.newSpriteSet(spriteSheet, 1, 7)
sprite.add(monsterSet, "running", 1, 6, 600, 0)
local monster = sprite.newSprite(monsterSet)
monster:prepare("running")
monster:play()
monster.x = 60
monster.y = 200
local monster2 = sprite.newSprite(monsterSet)
monster2:prepare("running")
monster2:play()
monster2.x = 420
monster2.y = 200
monster2.xScale = monster2.xScale * -1
local title = display.newImage("title.png")
title.x = 240
title.y = 80
local playButton = display.newImage("playButton.png")
playButton.x = 240
playButton.y = 220
menuDisplay:insert(background)
menuDisplay:insert(monster)
menuDisplay:insert(monster2)
menuDisplay:insert(title)
menuDisplay:insert(playButton)

local function buttonListener( event )
director:changeScene( "game", "downFlip" )
return true
end
    -
playButton:addEventListener("touch", buttonListener )

    return menuDisplay
end
```

i really need to fix this until friday becase is a project for a competition.

here is a link of error i get : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EylSo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have minus sign before `playButton:addEventListener("touch", buttonListener )` which prevents the file from compiling. That's probably why Corona doesn't load your file.

Comment: I tried running your code, but it references images you don't provide. Can you simplify your code that it doesn't reference any resources and run it as `main.lua` to see what errors it throws (you'll need to comment out `module`)?

Comment: i discovered the problem , the code is on Graphics v.1  and they updated it to v.2  and they deleted the sprite library , so i fixed that by downloading the spirte.lua from Git:D